# Access Localhost on other devices (Same Network)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, localhost

I have installed wordpress on my laptop and have been developing a website via WAMP. Localhost/wordpress works fine. Everytime I go to that, it brings me to my site. Great!

Now here is the thing. I want to be able to access the site throughout my home network. I.e. Testing it on my other devices/machines. Android Tablet etc...

I have done the ipconfig and am able to access my ip however when I go there, it just brings me to the WAMP Server Config. page. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.  If you need further information that I am not providing please let me know.

Comment: Just because someone has access to your Network does not mean that they have access to Programs on Your Computer, which is where localhost runs from.

Comment: Take a look at [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/). Vagrant allows you to set up a local host server, and will allow others to connect to it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I normally do it change `http://localhost/wordpress` via the Settings to the the [IP address](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/windows-7/find-your-local-ip-address-windows-7-cmd/) of the computer such as `http://192.168.1.10/wordpress` That will make your site `http://192.168.1.10/` accessible over the LAN.